# Bypass tcp/ip communication to service located on same server

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, soap

I'm working on a project that is located on 2 domains within same server:
 1. DataSource system, which provides data for main app 
 2. Main app, providing the data for front-end app.

App 1 needs to work on seperate domain, as it's data source for more applications. I'm trying to find some way to boost communication performance. Simple call from app 2 to app 1 takes approximately 0.3-0.4s.

Is there anyway to force server to bypass TCP/IP communication and call service directly from localhost?

Both applications are written in PHP with Zend Framework. The server is IIS. Both applications are based on SOAP solutions.

Would appreciate any tips. Will provide additional information if needed.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding here. If you call services from localhost (i.e. via Zend_HTTP_Client), this means you are using the tcp/ip and http layers here. Everything works via sockets, no matter if localhost or external ip address.

If the other application needs to be accessible "from the outside" (no integration possible) you can imho only speed up by using a faster webserver (e.g. nginx), turning off modules in your webserver that you don't need or writing your own socket server, dismissing a whole lot of the processing apache and nginx do. http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php may help you with your first steps.